# FindViewById returns NULL Scroll View

Tags: android, xml, view, scroll, null

I'm working on an android application and i have this problem. I want to add checkboxes dynamically in a scroll view which will be displayed in a dialog. 
The problem is layout is null when going through this expression `ScrollView layout = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.layout.custom);`

Here is the function.

```
private void openCustomMenu() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        ScrollView layout = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.layout.custom);
        layout.removeAllViews();
        for (String name : StopNames){
            CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);
            checkbox.setText(name);
            checkbox.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            layout.addView(checkbox);
        }

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(layout);
        dialog.setTitle("Bus Stops");
    }
```

And here my xml file.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/custom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </ScrollView>

Thank you for you help !
```

EDIT : new XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/custom">

        </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

and new function.

```
private void openCustomMenu() {




final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
        dialog.setTitle("Bus Stops");

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom);      
        layout.removeAllViews();
        for (String name : StopNames){
            CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);
            checkbox.setText(name);
            checkbox.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            layout.addView(checkbox);
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `findViewById(R.layout.custom);` to `findViewById(R.id.custom);` , so in your code, do this :

```
 ScrollView layout = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.custom);
```

you are trying to get the `id` from the `layouts` and not from the `ids`.

Comment: Thank you ! Now I don't get any errors but the dialog window doesn't appear at all. I changed a little bit my xml.

Comment: you didn't change ´R.layout.custom´ to ´findViewById(R.id.custom);´ , in your code . and if this answer answereed your question you should accept it. Then, you have to ask another question if you have another problem.